# How to scrape the product names from the website through Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I am trying to scrape this page: https://redmart.com/fresh-produce/fresh-vegetables. But the problem I face is it returns only some elements. 
Code I have used is below:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver

# Start the WebDriver and load the page
wd = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Chrome\chromedriver.exe")
wd.get('https://redmart.com/fresh-produce/fresh-vegetables')

# Wait for the dynamically loaded elements to show up
WebDriverWait(wd, 300).until(
EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "productDescriptionAndPrice")))

# And grab the page HTML source
html_page = wd.page_source
wd.quit()

# Now you can use html_page as you like
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

I needed to use Selenium becasue the source code is not useful as the page is JAVAscript generated. If you open the page, it has some 60 rows of products (around 360 products in total). Running this code only gives me 6 rows of products. Stopping at the yellow onions.

thanks!

Comment: Replace `WebDriverWait(wd, 300).until` to a static sleep for a long time. If it worked, means your wait is not sufficient.

Comment: The page is generating the elements as you scroll down. Adding scroll to the script will load more items. You may need to wait till the required number of items are loaded.

Comment: @JT What is your exact requirement? Are you trying to scrape all the 600 products?

Comment: Thanks guys for responding. In between i was trying things out. @DebanjanB yes i am trying to extract all products. 
I tried the sleep but as KDM mentioned, the items load as I scroll down. So I think I have to add some scrolling into the code. 
I also did manual scrolling, so as the page pops up, I added a time.sleep(30), and during this time, I manually used my mouse to scroll until all 600 products are revealed, and I reached the bottom of the page. The code then takes over, but this time I got only the last 22 lines of products out of 60 lines....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your question and the website `https://redmart.com/fresh-produce/fresh-vegetables`, *Selenium* can alone easily scrape all the *Product Names*. As you mentioned there are *around 360 products in total* but only *around 35 products* are from a particular *Class* for which I am providing you a solution which is as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  item_names = []
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://redmart.com/fresh-produce/fresh-vegetables")
  titles = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='productDescriptionAndPrice']//h4/a")))
  for title in titles:
      item_names.append(title.text)
  try:
      driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
      titles = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='productDescriptionAndPrice']//h4/a")))
      for title in titles:
      item_names.append(title.text)
  except:
      pass
  for item_name in item_names:
      print(item_name)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Eco Leaf Baby Spinach Fresh Vegetable
  Eco Leaf Kale Fresh Vegetable
  Sustenir Agriculture Almighty Arugula
  Sustenir Fresh Toscano Black Kale
  Sustenir Fresh Kinky Green Curly Kale
  ThyGrace Honey Cherry Tomato
  Australian Broccoli
  Sustenir Agriculture Italian Basil
  GIVVO Japanese Cucumbers
  YUVVO Red Onions
  Australian Cauliflower
  YUVVO Spring Onion
  GIVVO Old Ginger
  GIVVO Cherry Grape Tomatoes
  YUVVO Holland Potato
  ThyGrace Traffic Light Capsicum Bell Peppers
  GIVVO Whole Garlic
  GIVVO Celery
  Eco Leaf Baby Spinach Fresh Vegetable
  Eco Leaf Kale Fresh Vegetable
  Sustenir Agriculture Almighty Arugula
  Sustenir Fresh Toscano Black Kale
  Sustenir Fresh Kinky Green Curly Kale
  ThyGrace Honey Cherry Tomato
  Australian Broccoli
  Sustenir Agriculture Italian Basil
  GIVVO Japanese Cucumbers
  YUVVO Red Onions
  Australian Cauliflower
  YUVVO Spring Onion
  GIVVO Old Ginger
  GIVVO Cherry Grape Tomatoes
  YUVVO Holland Potato
  ThyGrace Traffic Light Capsicum Bell Peppers
  GIVVO Whole Garlic
  GIVVO Celery
  ```

**Note**: You can construct a more robust *XPATH* or *CSS-SELECTOR* to include more *products* and extract the relevant *Product Names*.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code in Java that works. The test waits for 30 elements.

```
@Test
public void test1() {
    List<WebElement> found = new WebDriverWait(driver, 300).until(wd -> {
        List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("productDescriptionAndPrice"));
        if(elements.size() > 30)
            return elements ;
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.offsetHeight)");
        return null;
    });
    for (WebElement e : found) {
        System.out.println(e.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks KDM, Sorry I cannot run this code, as only have python. But did you get all ~600 products?

Comment: @JT i tried with only 30. Guess changing the number to 600 should work. The point is to scroll to end of page to load more items.

Comment: Hi KDM is this line missing some parts? 
   
   List<WebElement> found = new WebDriverWait(driver, 300).until(wd -> {

Answer (score 0):

Hi DebanjanB I appreciate your help. I have spent my whole day having a go at this. The real problem is in getting the full product list into the source code. If everything is in the source, I think can extract it out. I believe the source changes as you scroll down, and maybe thats why we all can extract 36 items only.

With this in mind, my tentative solution is as follows. It is not perfect, as I have to do further processing later to remove duplicates. If you have other ideas or can further optimize, I will be really grateful.

General idea is to scroll down, grab the source and append making 1 big long source code with overlaps. I got 1400+ products doing it this way for 360 product page which is why I say its a bad solution.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Start the WebDriver and load the page
wd = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Chrome\chromedriver.exe")
wd.delete_all_cookies()
wd.set_page_load_timeout(30)

wd.get('https://redmart.com/fresh-produce/fresh-vegetables#toggle=all')
time.sleep(5)

html_page = wd.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'lxml')

while True:
    wd.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
    time.sleep(3)
    html_page = wd.page_source
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'lxml')

    for element in soup2.body:
         soup.body.append(element) 
    time.sleep(2)

    #break condition
    new_height = wd.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
wd.quit()

results = soup.findAll('div', attrs='class':'productDescriptionAndPrice'})
len(results)
results[0] # this tally with the first product
results[-1] # this tallies with the last
```

To be honest pretty disappointed with this solution. Thanks and pls feel free to keep them coming keep them coming!

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer I have accommodated one single class only. Constructing a _xpath_ to cover multiple classes with give you more results. Logic would remain the same.

Comment: Sorry which other class, as I thought all products are under productDescriptionAndPrice class?

Comment: A bit of clarification,  _class_ remains the same but the effective _xpaths_ are different. So you need to construct a _xpath_ which will cover multiple nodes.